# What is the sum of $k$ normal random variables where $k$ is sampled from a Poisson distribution?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, poisson-distribution

Let's say you have a sequence of i.i.d. random variables $r_1,r_2,r_3,\dots$ that are distributed as $\mathcal N(0,1)$. Now, consider the process where we sample a $k$ from $\text{Pois}(\lambda)$ and let $z$ equal $$\sum_{i=1}^{k}r_i$$

My question is what the distribution of $z$ is?

My first guess is that it would be $\mathcal N(0,\lambda)$. I do not how I would proof this, however. The variance might be slightly larger due to the uncertainty introduced by the Poisson distribution, for example. Proving the mean is $0$ is easy by symmetry.

Comment: This is a compound Poisson RV of normal RVs. It is not going to be normal again. The unconditional density is easily given by the law of total probability. For if $K=k$ then the sum $R_1+R_2+\dotsc +R_k$ has density of that of a $\mathcal{N}(0, k)$ since sum of IID normals is normal again. The unconditional density is then given by weighting over the Poisson probabilities $f_Z(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \mathbb{P}(K=k) f(z|k)$ where $f(z|k)$ is the density of a $\mathcal{N}(0,k)$ RV, as mentioned prior. (Please indulge my use of conventional *uppercase RVs* and *lowercase values*)

Comment: @NapD.Lover: The above is essentially correct, but the justification "since independence means variances add" is wrong. That's a more general and less strong statement than the statement that the sum of independent normally distributed random variables is normally distributed.

Comment: @joriki thanks, I edited it. Slip of precision...

Comment: @NapD.Lover okay. I guess it approaches a normal distribution as $\lambda$ approaches infinity, right?

Comment: @PyRulez I don't think so. Using the law of total expectation you can similarly compute the characteristic function of $Z$ as $\phi_Z(u)=e^{\lambda(e^{-0.5u^2}-1)}$, if I am not mistaken. Since $u^2 \geq 0$ for all real $u$, the term next to $\lambda$ is negative, so as $\lambda \to \infty$ we get $\phi_Z(u)\to 0$.

Comment: Feel free to work out and verify these computations yourself and summarize it into an answer, by the way.

Answer (score 3):

If the sum is $Z=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{K}r_i$, then $Z$ does not have a normal distribution

In particular, $\mathbb P(Z=0)=\mathbb P(K=0)=e^{-\lambda} > 0$ while a normal distribution represents a continuous random variable with no point of positive probability

Comment: For my own knowledge: Is that a hint, that $Z$ has a descrete probability distribution?

Comment: @Fakemistake $Z$ has a mixture of a continuous distribution and a discrete point of positive probability

Answer (score 1):

The moments of even order of the normal distribution are:
$$
\begin{array}{c|r}
n & n\text{th moment} \\
\hline
2 & 1 \\
4 & 1\times3 \\
6 & 1\times3\times5 \\
8 & 1\times3\times5\times7 \\
\vdots & \vdots\qquad 
\end{array}
$$
The cumulants of even order of this compound Poisson distribution are consequently:
$$
\begin{array}{c|r}
n & n\text{th cumulant} \\
\hline
2 & 1\times\lambda \\
4 & 1\times3\times\lambda \\
6 & 1\times3\times5\times\lambda \\
8 & 1\times3\times5\times7\times\lambda \\
\vdots & \vdots\quad\quad\quad 
\end{array}
$$
This result can be derived by an application of the [law of total cumulance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_cumulance).

But the cumulants of even order of the normal distribution with expectation $0$ and variance $\lambda$ are:
$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
n & n\text{th cumulant} \\
\hline
2 & \lambda \\
4 & 0 \\
6 & 0 \\
8 & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots
\end{array}
$$
Therefore this compound Poisson distribution is not a normal distribution.

But for now I have to leave this as this partial answer.